# python to print html file to default printer

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, printing

I want to print html file via default printer on windows os
I am already doing this using  code:

```
import os

os.startfile("C:\\Users\\user\Desktop\\table.html", "print")
```

the problem is no colors and no background color for table fields and page.
[image]

and the actual table on browser:
[image]

so how to print with actual colors?

Comment: why don't you give an answer better than such a comment !

Comment: Maybe I don't have the answer to your question? FYI, you forgot to mention which browser the HTML file is launched with.

Comment: Maybe there's a CSS file that's not being loaded because the URL is for a local filesystem file and not HTTP?

Comment: no im using inline formating

Comment: @ ThiefMaster :it is not about browser you can use any one to get the same result..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your printer defaults to b&w, if so, try to change that setting and then run your script again.

You could also try to first convert the html file to a pdf using [pdfkit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit/0.4.1):

```
import os    
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_file("C:\\Users\\user\Desktop\\table.html", "out.pdf")
os.startfile("out.pdf", "print")
```